# How to set alpha of static UITableViewCell on startup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm making an application, which has a Settings page. For the Settings page, I am using a `UITableViewController` with **static** `UITableViewCells`. I am using `NSUserDefaults` to store the settings.

Now, this is the Settings View Controller :

[image]

According to the code in the `viewDidLoad` function in the `SettingsTableViewController.m`, there is supposed to be a check on the saved setting, and depending on that, the `alpha` property of the *Notification Interval* cell is supposed to change. This works fine if I do it in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, however, it is not working in the `viewDidLoad` method. Here's the source :

```
#import "SettingsTableViewController.h"

@interface SettingsTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation SettingsTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // Check if setting is already saved.
    if ([defaults stringForKey:@"notification"]) {
        self.notificationTableViewCell.detailTextLabel.text = [defaults stringForKey:@"notification"];
        // Disable the interval cell, if the notifications are turned off.
        if([[defaults stringForKey:@"notification"] isEqualToString:@"Off"]) {
            self.intervalTableViewCell.alpha = 0.439216f;
            self.intervalTableViewCell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        }
    } else {
        // If no setting is saved, reset to default settings.
        self.notificationTableViewCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"On";
        [defaults setObject:@"On" forKey:@"notification"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }

    // Check if setting is already saved.
    if([defaults stringForKey:@"interval"]) {
        self.intervalTableViewCell.detailTextLabel.text = [defaults stringForKey:@"interval"];
    } else {
        // If no setting is saved, reset to default settings.
        self.intervalTableViewCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"5 min";
        [defaults setObject:@"5 min" forKey:@"interval"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Get selected cell.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Reset the state of the cell.
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if(cell == self.notificationTableViewCell) {
        if([cell.detailTextLabel.text isEqual: @"On"]) {
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Off";
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Off" forKey:@"notification"];
            self.intervalTableViewCell.alpha = 0.439216f;
            self.intervalTableViewCell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        } else {
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"On";
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"On" forKey:@"notification"];
            self.intervalTableViewCell.alpha = 1.0f;
            self.intervalTableViewCell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }

    } else if(cell == self.intervalTableViewCell) {
        NSArray *possibleTimes = @[@"1 min", @"5 min", @"10 min", @"30 min"];
        int indexOfCurrent = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < possibleTimes.count; i++) {
            if([self.intervalTableViewCell.detailTextLabel.text isEqualToString:possibleTimes[i]]) {
                indexOfCurrent = i;
            }
        }

        // Return to the starting value of the array.
        if(++indexOfCurrent == possibleTimes.count) {
            indexOfCurrent = 0;
        }

        self.intervalTableViewCell.detailTextLabel.text = possibleTimes[indexOfCurrent];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:possibleTimes[indexOfCurrent] forKey:@"interval"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: can you explicit your problem a little bit more ? is your problem alpha is not applied when view appears ?

Comment: Is `self.intervalTableViewCell == nil` in `viewDidLoad` because you first construct it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @Niko Yes. If I open the application and toggle the Notifications button, then when the settings comes to `Off`, the Notification Interval cell is greyed out. However, the same thing is not working in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Will that be relevant ? These cells are `static`. Also, the `.userInteractionEnabled` property can be changed from `viewDidLoad` itself. Its just the `alpha` that is not changing.

Comment: can you show us your cellForRowAtIndexPath code ?

Comment: It will certainly be relevant if your cell is `nil`, yes. If you are convinced that you can change other properties (i.e. `userInteractionEnabled` or `backgroundColor`) in `viewDidLoad`, then the only other explanation is that you're setting `alpha` to `1.0` somewhere else or the `UITableView` does this internally when it displays the cell.

Comment: @Niko The cells are `static`. I have designed them in the Interface Builder. There is no implementation of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: If you can change the `backgroundColor`, but not the `alpha`, you might want to change the `alpha` of the `backgroundColor` and then `alpha` of your cell's subviews. It's more verbose (and not exactly the same), but if `UITableView` is messing with your `alpha`, you have to do something different. Alternatively, you could create a `UITableViewCell` subclass and override `setAlpha` to change its maximum allowed value based on `userInteractionEnabled`.

Comment: @IanMacDonald This is rather peculiar, I must say. I am able to set `backgroundColor`, but not `alpha`. Right now, I simply changed the alpha values of the `subviews`, however, I still am wondering why changing the `alpha` property of the cell itself doesn't work.

Comment: It seems likely that the `UITableView` is setting the `alpha` of your cell. If you want to know for sure, subclass `UITableViewCell` for these cells and put a breakpoint inside `setAlpha` to see who sets it back to `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

First of as NSString comparation method you should use this:

```
isEqualToString:
```

instead of

```
isEqualToString:
```

Second thing is the way you find if selected cell is the one you want to check is not the best idea, I mean this:

```
if(cell == self.notificationTableViewCell)
```

Don't do that - you will find yourself in a huge troubles pretty quickly.
Proper way of handling that is to use enumerations, and switch case based on indexPath section, row values. Otherwise you keep a reference to a memory where cell is, but this cell is gonna be reused, by queuing mechanism of UITableView, for a different row - so you're gonna end up keeping some random reference to random cells at the end here.

For the alpha problem I think you should reload table data after you synchronize NSUserDefaults inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.
Use `reloadData` method from UITableView, or even better reload only the section you know that's gonna change on click (optimized version, but you can start with reloading whole table).

Answer (score 0):

Move the code that changes the `alpha` property of the cell into a method that occurs later in the view lifecycle. A good one to try would be `viewWillAppear:`.